# Georeferencing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff

When I work with ArcGIS and georeference a picture, my picture (Tif) remains the same but new files are being created:

- .tfwx .aux (XML) .ovr

The data of georeferenced picture are being stored within these files.

When I work wit Qgis, i get a modified picture and only the .ovr file.

I was wondering if there is a way to georeference in QGIS as it is being done in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 4):

You can still keep your original picture in QGIS as well. QGIS creates a GeoTIFF when you hit the green play button. You can even choose where you want this newly created GeoTIFF to be exported to by clicking on the tranformation properties (yellow cogwheel).

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I understand that a GeoTiff will be created. However, is it possible to avoid this and to get the data stored in the .tfwx .aux .ovr  like in ArcGIS. And if so how do i do that?

Comment: Does the georeferencer not ask after running it if you want to save the points you have created? That is basically the file with the data without the image. I believe however that the geoTiff will always be created. However you can choose to not load in to your map.

Comment: So it is not possible to create the exact same files as in ArcGis?